# Enable Wi-fi on Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I just installed Kali Linux on Dell Inspiron 1545, and am unable to get wireless connection.

I attempted the following

```
root@kali:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]

# apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
# modprobe -r iwlwifi; modprobe iwlwifi
```

I even tried commands I used when I installed Ubuntu on the same laptop

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

How to fix?

## UPDATE

I also ran

`sudo apt-get install kali-linux-wireless`

but I still cannot detect and connect to my home wi-fi.

Thanks!

## Tried first solution

I tried first solution, but when I go to Administration > System, I get package manager. I searched for everything `Broadcom` downloaded, installed, rebooted, but still no wireless.

There has to be an easy solution ......

Am trying this, http://www.chokepoint.net/2014/04/installing-broadcom-bcm43142-drivers-on.html

I was getting errors with install. After I reboot, still no wireless detector.

## Update

I'm trying all your suggestions .... seems I will have to read the links you provided. Who knew getting wireless would be so difficult! I will extend bounty time if possible.

Comment: Please read [editing guidelines](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and modify your question.

Comment: will do so ... why the down vote for something so trivial?

Comment: Trivial!! This is not trivial. Properly framing your question is THE most important part of asking a question on the SE network. Moreover, the downvote is not permanent. Edit your question properly and it might go away.

Comment: okay okay calm down ... I fixed ... kindly upvote if you wish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be your wireless card is in turned off state, does the laptop have any dedicated physical switch or key combo(like Fn+F3 on my acer laptop) to turn on/off Wi-Fi ? most laptops also have a LED to show Wi-Fi card state.

Device firmwares are not pre installed in kali-linux(my last used version 1.0.4 can't tell about latest versions) , so if not already installed, install them.

`sudo apt-get install firmware-linux firmware-linux-free firmware-linux-nonfree`

Install Broadcom wireless card firmware

`sudo apt-get install firmware-brcm80211 firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer broadcom-sta-dkms`

Then use proper kernel drivers, b43 or b43legacy, iwlwifi is Intel Wi-Fi card driver so *firmware-iwlwifi* is not necessary.

Comment: I am installing in Dell Inspiron 1545 ... will try this

Comment: @Arnam I tried the two commands, but no luck. What do you mean by `Then use proper kernel drivers, b43 or b43legacy, iwlwifi is Intel Wi-Fi card driver so firmware-iwlwifi is not necessary.`

Comment: As your Wi-Fi module is made by Broadcom , so it is unnecessary to use any Intel Wi-Fi card driver, **iwlwifi** kernel module is for Intel Wi-Fi modules. Does the Wi-Fi interface shows up(check with `/sbin/ifconfig`) as wlan0 or even as eth1 ? I think your card needs Proprietary **Broadcom STA Wireless** driver , did you installed this ? **broadcom-sta-dkms** ? About 1yr ago I had same issue with an old lenovo laptop , but finally worked smoothly on Ubuntu with **bcmwl-kernel-source** package. check it here https://wiki.debian.org/wl , and hey, my name is _Arnab_ not _Arnam_ .

Comment: sorry about the typo :-) will check this

Comment: @Arnam Your answer gave me great ideas

Comment: Fn + F2 on some devices, but thats not a solution. It only can set soft blocked yes to no. It can not do anything to hard blocked yes. This is a hardware issue, not software. If it is just not showing wifi go to this video:     https://youtu.be/Z4ueXndm90o

Answer (score 2):

The following question in AskUbuntu resembles to this question and the best chosen answer suggests to perform the following steps:

```
Go to: System->Administrator->Additional Drivers(Hardware drivers)

Then click to Broadcom STA wireless driver and enable it.

Restart
```

Although, this is for Ubuntu, the best way to:

```
  Open System Settings --> Software & Updates.

  In the Softwares & Updates screen, head over to Additional Drivers and
  follow the instructions from there on.
```

I have personally never faced such an issue before and so I do not know what to do next :/

Comment: Will try this very soon

Comment: These options do not appear anywhere. And there is no search in Kali LInux!

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Kali Linux on a Macbook Pro. The macbook also uses the broadcom device drivers.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r | sed ‘s,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,’) broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
modprobe wl
```

You can find the instructions on how to make this work [here](https://pentestmac.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/kali-linux-broadcom-wireless-on-macbook/).

Comment: Hi! It would be best if you explained what your call to sed is meant to do.

Comment: Not sure exactly, but the debian wiki recommends this command for installing the broadcom devices. Take a look at part 2 of these installation instructions :-
https://wiki.debian.org/wl

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`

Also, if that won't work, look here: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1428

It seems someone made it work... in Mint, but still...

If you couldn't find the package:
https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/firmware-b43-lpphy-installer

...you need b43-lpphy driver aka low-power