# Wireless connection in kali linux

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux

I installed kali-linux-1.0.8-amd64 in my dell inspiron 3520 PC. 
I can't connect via wireless card. I think it isn't recognized by the system.

(I can't connect via ethernet cause I can access to the modem just via wifi, I uses another windows pc)

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:8d:f1:3d  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
hwsim0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 12-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:10216 (9.9 KiB)  TX bytes:10216 (9.9 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:00:00:00  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:00:01:00  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` show :

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ifconfig -a`? Also, what type of wireless card do you have?

Comment: Hi I edited my post as you asked  thank you ^^

Comment: I am not sure of the answer, but this link may be of some use: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209356/enable-wi-fi-on-kali-linux?rq=1

Comment: @Peschke  I tried the answer in the link you offered me but i have : unable to locate broadcom-sta-dkms