# Can't enable wifi, but my Wifi LED indicator always turned on

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I just installed kali linux in my asus laptop, but I can't enable the wifi. 
and the problem is, I can't do it with my function key (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) for enabling WiFi, because the LED indicator for WiFi is always turned on.

iwconfig result:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

---

and airmon-ng result:

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

---

it's weird for me. My wifi card was detected by Kali, but I still can't enable it.

Comment: What is the actual problem, the iwconfig says Tx-Power=15 dBm so it is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is the internal laptop WiFi card were discussing?

Do you need to install device firmware? [Check out this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209356/enable-wi-fi-on-kali-linux), seems to have some good pointers regarding where to start at least.