# I can't install a driver for the wifi adaptor on Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, drivers, vmware, usb-device

I'm a new user of Kali Linux 2020.4 (Kernel 5.9.0-kali1-amd64)

I bought a wifi USB adaptor TP-Link-TL-WN822N(eu) ver 5.2. Chipset is Realtek RTL8192EU.

Right after installation of Kali Linux on VMWare 15 Workstation Pro (host OS is Win10). I connected USB Adaptor and wireless networks were been detected.
But connecting to my router and smartphone by used wifi hasn't been Successfully.
After some time "Configuring Interface" connection deactivating from my Access Points.

Well, how I tried this problem:

1)

```
lsusb
```

output:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0108 TP-Link TL-WN822N Version 4 RTL8192EU`

2)

```
sudo Airmon-ng
```

output:

```
phy1    wlan0           rtl8xxxu        TP-Link TL-WN822N Version 4 RTL8192EU
```

3. iwconfig has been detected wlan0

So, I'm trying to install driver for RTL8192EU from here https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

> This driver is based on the (latest) official Realtek v5.2.19.1 driver with fixes and improvements to support the latest kernels (up to 5.11)

I've Kernel 5.9 :)

```
sudo apt list linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

it's done Successfully.

After this, I'm downloading the zip file and extract it to folder Home.
After I'm opening a terminal in this folder.

```
sudo ./install_wifi.sh
```

output

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module 8192eu is not currently loaded

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.0
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8192eu-1.0

DKMS: add completed.
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 5.9.0-kali1-amd64 cannot be found at
/lib/modules/5.9.0-kali1-amd64/build or /lib/modules/5.9.0-kali1-amd64/source.
You can use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.9.0-kali1-amd64
```

what is mean? Can I fix this error?

```
dkms status
output: rtl8192eu, 1.0: added

sudo rmmod 8192eu
output: rmmod: ERROR: Module 8192eu is not currently loaded

sudo rmmod rtl8xxxu                                                            1 ⨯
output:rmmod: ERROR: Module rtl8xxxu is not currently loaded


sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/1.0 --all                                           1 ⨯
output:
```

---

```
Deleting module version: 1.0
completely from the DKMS tree
```

---

```
Done.
```

after:

```
sudo dkms add .

output: Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8192eu-1.0

DKMS: add completed.
```

after:

```
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
output: Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 5.9.0-kali1-amd64 cannot be found at
/lib/modules/5.9.0-kali1-amd64/build or /lib/modules/5.9.0-kali1-amd64/source.
You can use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.
```

I understand what after the first error I may even don't continue to write code. Help me, please. How I can run this wifi adaptor on Kali?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable Wi-fi on Kali Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209356/enable-wi-fi-on-kali-linux)

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Kali is a distribution meant for experienced users to run in a virtual machine, and if you want a user-friendly distribution or need something with drivers for your hardware please use elementary OS, Linux Mint or Ubuntu instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment soon, Unfortunately, I need only Kali Linux for pentesting

Comment: Kali Linux is not suitable for most hardware requiring closed source firmware or drivers like Wi-Fi chips. Therefore keep Kali in a Virtual Machine and you're done. Run the VM on Ubuntu or similar with KVM/QEMU/libvirt.

Comment: PS: The Edimax N150 "Wi-Fi Nano USB Adapter" EW-7811UN works for me in Kali Linux.

Comment: @Ned64 it is not the same issue.